# How would I make my clear cart button work?

Tags: javascript, html

So I got my cart page functioning pretty well and I want to know how to make my Clear Cart button remove every item from the cart if possible.

Here's my code:

```js
var cart = [];

function Item(name, price, count) {
  this.name = name
  this.price = price
  this.count = count
};


var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart');
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
}

function addToCartClicked(name, price) {
  if (cart === null) {
    cart = [];
  }
  var parent1 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemName');
  var name = parent1[0].textContent;
  console.log("1st child of parent1");
  console.log(name)
  var parent2 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemPrice');
  var price = Number(parent2[0].textContent);
  console.log("1st child of parent2");
  console.log(price);

  const Item = {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    count: 1,

  };
  console.log(Item);

  addItemToCart(name, price, 1);

  displayCart();
}



function addItemToCart(name, price, count) {
  for (var i in cart) {
    if (cart[i].name === name && cart[i].price === price) {
      cart[i].count += count;

      saveCart();
      return;
    }

  }
  var item = new Item(name, price, count);
  cart.push(item);
  saveCart();
}
console.log("add to cart");
console.log(cart);



function listCart() {
  var cartCopy = [];
  for (var i in cart) {
    var item = cart[i];
    var itemCopy = {};
    for (var p in item) {
      itemCopy[p] = item[p];
    }
    itemCopy.total = (item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
    cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
  }
  return cartCopy;
};

function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = listCart();
  var output = "";

  for (var i in cartArray) {
    output += "<div class='itemDetail'>" +
      "<div class='cart-item cart-column'>" +
      cartArray[i].name +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='cart-price cart-column'>" +
      " $ " + cartArray[i].price +
      "</div>" +
      " <input class='item-count cart-column' type='number' data-name='" +
      cartArray[i].name +
      "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>" +
      "<div class='subTotal cart-column'>" +
      "  $ " + cartArray[i].total +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>";
  }
  $("#show-cart").html(output);
  $("#count-cart").html(countCart());
  $("#total-cart").html(totalCart());

}


function setCountForItem(name, price, count) {
  for (var i in cart) {
    if (cart[i].name === name) {
      cart[i].count = count;
      if (cart[i].count == 0) {
        cart.splice(i, 1);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  saveCart();
};


function removeItemFromCart(name, price, count) {
  for (var i in cart) {
    if (cart[i].name === name) {
      cart[i].count--;
      if (cart[i].count == 0) {
        cart.splice(i, 1);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  saveCart();
};



function countCart() {
  var totalCount = 0;
  for (var i in cart) {
    totalCount += cart[i].count;
  }
  return totalCount;
};


function totalCart() {
  var totalCost = 0;
  for (var i in cart) {
    totalCost += cart[i].price * cart[i].count;
  }
  return totalCost.toFixed(2);
};


function saveCart() {
  localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
};


function loadCart() {
  cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));

};


loadCart();
displayCart();


$("#show-cart").on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {

  var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
  var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
  var count = Number($(this).val());

  setCountForItem(name, price, count);
  displayCart();
});

/*ITEM 2 */
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart2');
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked2);
}

function addToCartClicked2() {
  var parent1 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemName2');
  var name = parent1[0].textContent;
  console.log("1st child of parent1");
  console.log(name)
  var parent2 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemPrice2');
  var price = Number(parent2[0].textContent);
  console.log("1st child of parent2");
  console.log(price);

  addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
  displayCart();
}
/*ITEM 3 */
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart3');
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked3);
}

function addToCartClicked3() {
  var parent1 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemName3');
  var name = parent1[0].textContent;
  console.log("1st child of parent1");
  console.log(name)
  var parent2 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemPrice3');
  var price = Number(parent2[0].textContent);
  console.log("1st child of parent2");
  console.log(price);
  addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
  displayCart();
}
/*ITEM 4 */
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart4');
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked4);
}

function addToCartClicked4() {
  var parent1 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemName4');
  var name = parent1[0].textContent;
  console.log("1st child of parent1");
  console.log(name)
  var parent2 = document.querySelectorAll('#itemPrice4');
  var price = Number(parent2[0].textContent);
  console.log("1st child of parent2");
  console.log(price);
  addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
  displayCart();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec308a8989.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Cart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styleCart.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img style="float: left;" src="assets/img/mine.png" width="200" height="80" onclick="Home()">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navborder" href="Tacos.html">Tacos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navborder" href="Burritos.html">Burritos</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navborder" href="drinks.html">Drinks</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navborder" href="desert.html">Deserts</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="navborder" href="SpecialMenu.html">Special Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="navborder" href="Cart.html">Checkout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <p1>NOW AVAILABLE ON UBER-EATS! </p1>
  <h1>CART</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="card">
      <a name="cartSection"></a>
      <div class="cart-row">
        <div class="cart-item-name cart-header cart-column">Item</div>
        <div class="cart-price-header cart-header cart-column">Price</div>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">Quantity</div>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">Sub-total</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-items">
        <ul id="show-cart">
          <span-cart>Your cart is empty!</span-cart>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="cart-total">Total Cart:$<span id="total-cart"></span></div><br><br>
      <button id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button><br><br><br>
      <button type="button" value="Check Out" id="checkOut" onclick="purchase()">Check Out</button>

    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="js/ItemScripts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/drinks.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scriptsCart.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scriptsBurrito.js"></script>
  <script src="js/desert.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scriptsMisc.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to copy the remove item code with a clearCartClicked function that I removed from the code but it didn't work.

Also sorry if the question is worded poorly this is my first question on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your cart items in the `cart` variable, so, if you want to clear it, you can simply reassign its value to an empty array, like this:

```js
cart = [];
```

You are also persisting it in the localStorage as `shoppingCart`, so if you want to reflect the change, you also need to update that entry in the localStorage. For that, you can use the `saveCart()` function you have created.

A quick and dirty example:

```js
let cart = [];

const cartViewElement = document.querySelector('#cart');

function addNewItemToCart() {
  // Use the length of the cart to create a new ID
  const id = cart.length + 1;
  
  cart.push(`Item ${id}`);
  displayCart();
}

function clearCart() {
  // Remove everything from the cart
  cart = [];
  displayCart();
}

function displayCart() {
  const cartItems = [];

  // if there are items in the cart, create one <li> element for each
  // cart item and store them in an array. Else, add the message "empty"
  if (cart.length > 0) {
    for (const item of cart) {
      const cartItemElement = document.createElement('li');
      cartItemElement.innerHTML = item;
      cartItems.push(cartItemElement);  
    }  
  } else {
    cartItems.push('empty');
  }
  
  // replace the html content of the cart view with the new cart items
  cartViewElement.replaceChildren(...cartItems);
}

// Listen to click events on #addNewItemToCart button and call addNewItemToCart()
document.querySelector('#addNewItemToCart')
  .addEventListener('click', addNewItemToCart);
  
// Listen to click events on #clearCart button and call clearCart()
document.querySelector('#clearCart')
  .addEventListener('click', clearCart);
  
displayCart();
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="addNewItemToCart">Add new item</button>
  <button id="clearCart">Clear</button>
</div>

<h1> My Cart </h1>
<ul id="cart"></ul>
```

If you define `cart` with `const` instead of `let`, you won't be able to assign a new value to it, but you can still remove all items from the array using the `Array.pop()` method, like this:

```js
const cart = [];

function clearCart() {
  while (cart.length > 0) cart.pop();
}
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop